# Unable to send broadcast to service from activity

Tags: android, android-activity, service, broadcast

I am trying to send a broadcast to service which is found in another package. My activity connects to the service via bindService. I noticed that When I send the broadcast, this never gets received by the service, except if I send the broadcast within the onServiceConnected method, it gets received and everything works perfectly! Whe is it that, if I do sendBroadcast in any other part of my activity, this broadcast never gets received? To be more specific, my service registers a local broadcast so it does the register and unregister within the onCreate and onDestroy methods:

This is the code from Application_A which send the broadcast to the service. In the onStart method it launches the remote service and binds to it, in the onConnected Method it correctly executes the broadcast. On the other hand, when I click the button, it doesn't send the broadcast but it does show the toast.

```
   package com.example.app_a;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.PendingIntent.CanceledException;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivityA extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private ImageButton button;
    private EditText inputEditText;
    private boolean mIsBound = false;
    private Intent in;
    private static final String MSG_CHANGE_TEXT_COLOR = "CHANGE_TEXT_COLOR";
    private static final String BroadCast_Filter = "com.example.app_a";


    private class AppReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }





    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection()
    {



        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             mIsBound = true;
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECTED TO SERVICE!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setAction("com.example.talker_service.Communicate");

             /*
             intent.putExtra("REQUEST", "REGISTER APP");

             intent.putExtra("FILTER", BroadCast_Filter);
             intent.putExtra("NAME", getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "APP NAME: "+getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             String[] components = {"NUMBER_SENT",MSG_CHANGE_TEXT_COLOR,"CHANGE_TEXTVIEW_SIZE"};
             intent.putExtra("COMPONENTS", components);

             sendBroadcast(intent);

             */

             intent.putExtra("REQUEST","SEND" );
             intent.putExtra("FILTER", BroadCast_Filter);
             intent.putExtra("COMPONENT", MSG_CHANGE_TEXT_COLOR );
             intent.putExtra("DATA", "#000099");
             MainActivityA.this.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mIsBound = false;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECTION LOST FROM APP_A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.invioImageButton);
        inputEditText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.inputEditTetxt);


         button.setOnClickListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();

        //Bind to service

        in = new Intent();
        in.setClassName("com.example.app_talker_service", "com.example.app_talker_service.Talker_Service");

        //this.startService(in);
        bindService(in, mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        //startService(new Intent("com.example.app_b.exampleservice"));


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        //this.stopService(in);
        /*if(mIsBound)
        {
            getApplicationContext().unbindService(mConnection);
            mIsBound = false;
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.invioImageButton:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BUTTON PRESSED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            in.setClassName("com.example.app_talker_service", "com.example.talker_service.Communicate");
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra("REQUEST","SEND" );
            intent.putExtra("FILTER", BroadCast_Filter);
            intent.putExtra("COMPONENT", MSG_CHANGE_TEXT_COLOR );
            intent.putExtra("DATA", "#5C5CE6");

            MainActivityA.this.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

The service is located in another package and sends perfectly any broadcast, but somehow, it won't reveice them from the activiies, if these are not sent within the onserviceconnected method. I can't post all the code for the class is large, but i will show you the main parts. NOtice that the service is only a buonded service so it does not work with ServiceIntent, but it has a handler in order to communicate with Message type data. However I am trying to use broadcast for personal reasons:

```
package com.example.app_talker_service;
public class Talker_Service extends Service 
{
    private RegistryDB registry;
    private TalkerService_Receiver receiver;
    private IntentFilter filter;
    public final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());
    ...
    ...
    ...

    public class TalkerService_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
         ...
         ...
         ...
         }

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    registry = new RegistryDB(this.getApplicationContext());

    receiver = new TalkerService_Receiver();
    filter = new IntentFilter("com.example.talker_service.Communicate");
    this.registerReceiver(receiver,filter );
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " RECEIVER REGISTERED", 

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onCreate();
    }

@Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " RECEIVER UNREGISTERED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    this.registerReceiver(receiver,filter );
    return mMessenger.getBinder();
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why is it that broadcasts seem not to work when I do no send them withing the onconnected method? Is it possible to send broadcasts to service from activities?

Comment: Why are you sending broadcasts when you are already binding to the service (and can send anything you want via the ServiceConnection)?

Comment: Do you mean implementing a Messenger (Ibinder)?If so then I know how to do that. I am working on a particular project and I am trying to see if it is possible to send broadcast to services the way i explained it above...Is it possible to do so?